# RabbitMQ Retrieve an object in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have this consumer class who is using the @RabbitListener annotation and I need to retrieve the object which I'm getting in the Payload:

```
@Component
public class RabbitMQService {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RabbitMQService.class);

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${peopleevents.queue}")
    public void receivedMessage(@Payload Message message) throws JsonProcessingException {

        String json = "";

        json = new String(message.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        logger.info("Received message: {}", json);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        PeopleCoresConsumerDTO consumerDTO = objectMapper.readValue(json, PeopleCoresConsumerDTO.class);
        logger.info("Received message is.. " + message.toString());
    }
```

I'm using objectmapper to get it but I think that I'm missing something here to completely retrieve the object back, but I don't know what? Any help!!??

The DTO is as follows:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class PeopleCoresConsumerDTO {

    @JsonProperty(value = "processType")
    @NotNull(message = "ProcessType is mandatory")
    private String processType;

    @JsonProperty(value = "operation")
    @NotNull(message = "Operation is mandatory")
    private String operation;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Entity")
    @NotNull(message = "Entity is mandatory")
    private String entity;

    @JsonProperty(value = "EntityType")
    @NotNull(message = "EntityType is mandatory")
    private String entityType;

    @JsonProperty(value = "IdCuco")
    @NotNull(message = "IdCuco is mandatory")
    private Long idCuco;

    @JsonProperty(value = "PersonF")
    private PersonF personF;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Address")
    private Address address;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Document")
    private Document document;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Ban")
    private Ban ban;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Dates")
    private PeopleDate date;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    class Customer {
        private String systemId;
        private String customerId;
    }

    private List<Customer> customers;

}
```

Comment: what the JSON you get looks like?

Comment: What do you mean? Where?

Comment: I mean your message body, and this variable : json = new String(message.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Comment: and where you I see that? Sorry if it's a silly Q

Comment: In your RabbitMQService class in method receivedMessage you have this line of code :   json = new String(message.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); I'm asking about this json variable, how it looks like?

Comment: I know that line, but what I'm not sure is where can I see the value of that json variable

Comment: You have that one next `logger.info("Received message: {}", json);`. so, definitely should see that JSON in logs. The `ObjectMapper` can deserialize data from the `byte[]` - no need to convert it to `String` upfront. Spring AMQP can do that for you automatically after configuring respective `MessageConverter`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#message-converters. Perhaps your question is more about JSON (de)serialization and mapping to some model and back, rather than about Spring AMQP and Spring Boot...

Comment: YEs! I need to map to the DTO class I post. That's why I'm using objectmapper. But if not converting to string, what the json parameter in PeopleCoresConsumerDTO consumerDTO = objectMapper.readValue(json, PeopleCoresConsumerDTO.class); should be?

Comment: I mean there is `readValue(byte[] src, Class<T> valueType)` API in the `ObjectMapper`. You probably need to start with small steps: take your `PeopleCoresConsumerDTO` into a simple unit test against some predefined JSON to be sure that this one is deserialized as expected to your model. Since we don't know what is that JSON, we cannot say what is wrong with your model. From the code perspective everything is OK. We really cannot help you if you don't specify a concrete problem. It is very vague for those who doesn't work in your project. How about if you remove that `@Payload`?..

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` `@Bean` to the context, and then

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = "${peopleevents.queue}")
public void receivedMessage(@Payload PeopleCoresConsumerDTO consumerDTO) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what should be inside the receivedMessage method? I already have that @Bean in my config class. Thanks!

Comment: Whatever you want the message deserialized to; looks like `PeopleCoresConsumerDTO`.